# Matching Largest Eigenvalues to Eigenvectors

Tags: python, pca, eigenvalue, eigenvector

In Python I've calculated the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of my data matrix `X` through `eig()`. I'm looking to find the **top 2 principal components** of the data (U = [u1 u2]). I know the top 2 components are the 2 eigenvectors corresponding to the 2 largest eigenvalues, but I'm not sure how to calculate that information with the data at hand (eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and X).

Eigenvectors and eigenvalues calculated:

```
 Eigenvectors = [[-0.68065502 -0.72805308 -0.08153196]
                 [-0.71680551  0.68482721 -0.13115467]
                 [-0.15132287  0.03082853  0.98800354]]

 Eigenvalues = [2.84217094e-14  2.15257831e+02  8.95193455e+02]
```

Comment: what are you looking to calculate? You already have all the information (eigval, eigvec). What do you need more ?

Comment: Looking to find the top 2 principal components for PCA

Comment: Then just take the maximum 2 of your 3 eigenvalues. They are the principal components.

Answer (score 0):

Given the Eigenvalues you got `Eigenvalues = [2.84217094e-14  2.15257831e+02  8.95193455e+02]`

Your two largest Eigenvalues are `8.95193455e+02 and 2.15257831e+02`,
The sum of your eigenvalues is `1110.0` which corresponds to the 100% of the information.
So your largest eigenvalue `8.95193455e+02` has 80.6% of the information. The second eigenvalue `2.15257831e+02` has the remaining 19.4% of the information, and the last eigenvalue `2.84217094e-14` is too small, thus it can be considered noise.

For the eigenvectors that match these eigenvalues, each column of your  `Eigenvectors` matrix is associated to one eigenvalue, and they are in the same order.

For example, your first eigenvalue `8.95193455e+02` is associated to the eigenvector

```
[[-0.08153196]
 [-0.13115467]
 [ 0.98800354]]
```